# Issue using Infragistics (v6) WebNumericEdit and WebDateChooser fields within .NET 2.0 SP2 and VS 2005 C#

Tags: infragistics

Im using a ASP form with infragistics (v6.3.20063.53 or v7.3.20073.38) fields. I need to assign values in javascript (client side) before the form is shown to user:

**Assigning values: (Javascript client side)**

document.getElementById("TBSalary").value = 1000;       // TBSalary is defined as WebNumericEdit field

document.getElementById("TBDate").value = "15/10/1966"; // TBDate is defined as WebDateChooser field

**HTML Code:**

< igtxt:WebNumericEdit ID="TBSalary" runat="server" MaxValue="500000" MinDecimalPlaces="Two" MinValue="0" TabIndex="3">< /igtxt:WebNumericEdit>

< igsch:WebDateChooser ID="TBDate" runat="server" Width="110px" Height="1px" TabIndex="8" NullDateLabel="">< /igsch:WebDateChooser>

But when the form appears to the user, the values are not displayed in the fields.

Assigning values in server side works ok but need to do that in client side.

Any ideas? Thanks

Using .NET FrameWork 2.0 SP2, Visual Studio 2005 and C#

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

Using WebHtmlEditor methods! Easy and simple!

Thank you!